# Is checking the type of an object in tests an accepted practice?

Tags: c++, testing

In my program I have a function that parses the command line arguments.

```
Command* parse(int argc, char **argv)
```

Class Command has only one virtual method: run(). Of course there are some subclasses.

Now I want to test the 'parse' function.
The plan includes calling 'parse' with various arguments and inspecting the output. Now, in order to check whether the output is correct, I need to inspect the real type of the returned object (for instance, that "./program --help" would result in a HelpCommand instance).

Is it an acceptable testing schema?

Comment: You could check that the type is correct, or you could just check that invoking `run()` on the returned object produces the correct result (or both).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that sounds like a perfectly suitable thing to test.